# how to batch rename files in terminal - move text in file name from end of file name to front

Tags: rename, wget

I have recently started using wget to download files.

I'm using ubuntu 16 mate to manipulate my files.

I create custom urls to include specific information that I want saved to the downloaded file name as follow:

```
  http://website.com/file.txt?title_Three_little_pigs_user_spinach_
```

If I download the url using Firefox and Downthemall using rename masks to add query strings to the file name I can manage to get:

```
  Three_little_pigs_user_spinach_file.txt
```

If I download the same urls using wget (which does not appear to support rename masking) I end up getting:

```
  file.txt@title_Three_little_pigs_user_spinach_
```

I there a way to batch rename files as follows:

Before:

```
  file.txt@title_Three_little_pigs_user_spinach_
```

After:

```
  title_Three_little_pigs_user_spinach_file.txt
```

I want to move the text after the @ to the beginning and then remove the @.

I have lots of files I want to rename in terminal in ubuntu - if I could add it to a bash script it would be awsome.

I run ubuntu and windows and I have not found a windows program that will rename files in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 should come with both the original perl-supplied `prename` and its newer replacement `rename`, either of which should work with a standard `sed`-like substitution expression

```
prename -n 's/(.*)@(.*)/$2$1/' *@*
```

or

```
rename -n 's/(.*)@(.*)/$2$1/' *@*
```

You could also install `mmv` from the repository, and use

```
mmv -n "*@*" "#2#1"
```

*In all cases the `-n` is a no-operation flag for testing - remove it once you are absolutely sure that the it's going to do what you want*